# Identify missing data in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
location_id device_id   phase   timestamp           date        day_no  hour    quarter_hour data_received  data_sent
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-01-30 00:00:00 2023-01-30  1       0       00:00:00        150             98  
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-01-30 00:15:00 2023-01-30  1       0       00:15:00        130             101
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-01-30 00:45:00 2023-01-30  1       0       00:45:00        121             75
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-01-30 01:00:00 2023-01-30  1       1       01:00:00        104             110
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-01-30 01:15:00 2023-01-30  1       1       01:15:00        85              79
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-01-30 01:30:00 2023-01-30  1       1       01:45:00        127             123
   .          .            .            .               .       .       .           .             .               .
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-02-03 23:30:00 2023-02-03  5       23      23:30:00        100             83
10001       1001        Phase 1 2023-02-03 23:45:00 2023-02-03  5       23      23:45:00        121             75
10001       1005        Phase 2 2023-02-15 02:15:00 2023-02-15  1       2       02:15:00        90              101
10001       1005        Phase 2 2023-02-15 02:30:00 2023-02-15  1       2       02:30:00        111             98
  .            .               .            .           .       .       .           .             .               .
10001       1005        Phase 2 2023-02-19 23:15:00 2023-02-19  5       23      23:15:00        154             76
10001       1005        Phase 2 2023-02-19 23:30:00 2023-02-19  5       23      23:30:00        97              101
10003       1010        Phase 2 2023-01-14 00:00:00 2023-01-14  1       0       00:00:00        112             87  
10003       1010        Phase 2 2023-01-14 00:15:00 2023-01-14  1       0       00:15:00        130             101
10003       1010        Phase 2 2023-01-14 00:30:00 2023-01-14  1       0       00:30:00        89              91
  .            .               .            .           .       .       .           .             .               .
10003       1010        Phase 2 2023-01-18 23:45:00 2023-01-18  5       23      23:45:00        123             117
```

Each location has various phases that happen one after the other and each phase has a device assigned to it and lasts 5 days. During the 5 days we get the status of device for every 15 mins as row in the dataframe. The dataframe can sometimes have missing rows of data or the device data for a previous phase can be missing too(not uploaded yet) and these missing rows need to be identified. Sometimes the device can be switched on after the phase has started and rows can be missing for the time when the device was switched off and these rows shouldn’t be identified as missing rows of data.  The output for the above dataframe would be as follows

```
location_id phase     day_no    hour quarter_hour 
10001       Phase 1     1       0   00:30:00
10001       Phase 2     5       23  23:45:00    
10003       Phase 1     1       0   00:00:00    
10003       Phase 1     1       0   00:15:00    
10003       Phase 1     1       0   00:30:00
  .            .        .       .       .   
10003       Phase 1     5       23  23:45:00
```

The following code works and I can identify all rows the missing of data but the code is very slow and especially below line is the bottleneck of my script.

```
day_quarter_hour_data_check = quarter_hourly_data_df[(quarter_hourly_data_df['location_id'].isin([location_id])) & (quarter_hourly_data_df['phase'].isin([phase])) & (quarter_hourly_data_df['day_no'].isin([cur_day])) & (quarter_hourly_data_df['quarter_hour'].isin([quarter_hour]))]['timestamp'] 


quarter_hourly_data_df = pd.read_csv('location_quarter_hourly_data.csv')
quarter_hourly_data_df = quarter_hourly_data_df.astype({'timestamp':'datetime64[ns]'})
quarter_hourly_data_df['quarter_hour'] = quarter_hourly_data_df['timestamp'].dt.time
start_times_data_df = quarter_hourly_data_df.groupby(['location_id','device_id','phase']).agg(start_time=pd.NamedAgg(column="timestamp", aggfunc="min"),day_no=pd.NamedAgg(column="day_no", aggfunc="min")).reset_index()
start_times_data_df['start_time'] = start_times_data_df['start_time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
start_times_data_df['quarter_hour'] = start_times_data_df['start_time'].dt.time

location_ids = start_times_data_df['location_id'].unique()
location_ids.sort()

phases = start_times_data_df['phase'].unique()
phases.sort()

location_phases_df = quarter_hourly_data_df[['location_id','phase']].drop_duplicates()
location_last_phase_df = location_phases_df.groupby(['location_id']).agg(last_phase=pd.NamedAgg(column='phase', aggfunc='max')).reset_index()

location_site_df = location_df[['site_id','location_id']].drop_duplicates()
location_site_df.rename(columns={"site_id": "site_no"}, inplace = True)

quarter_hours= pd.date_range("00:00", "23:45", freq="15min").time

location_phase_quarter_hour_missing_data = []

for location_id in location_ids:

    location_last_phase = location_last_phase_df[(location_last_phase_df['location_id'].isin([location_id]))]['last_phase'].values[0]

    for phase in phases:
        if int(phase[6]) <= int(location_last_phase[6]):
            # check if phase exists or not
            location_phase_data_check = start_times_data_df[(start_times_data_df['location_id'].isin([location_id])) & (start_times_data_df['phase'].isin([phase]))]['start_time']

            # if phase exists get start time of phase
            if not location_phase_data_check.empty:
                location_start_day = start_times_data_df[(start_times_data_df['location_id'].isin([location_id])) & (start_times_data_df['phase'].isin([phase]))]['day_no'].values[0]
                location_start_time = start_times_data_df[(start_times_data_df['location_id'].isin([location_id])) & (start_times_data_df['phase'].isin([phase]))]['quarter_hour'].values[0]

                for day_no in range(5):
                    cur_day = day_no+1

                    for quarter_hour in quarter_hours:
                        if ((quarter_hour >= location_start_time) and (cur_day >= location_start_day)) :
                            #check if data exists for every quarter hour after start time
                            day_quarter_hour_data_check = quarter_hourly_data_df[(quarter_hourly_data_df['location_id'].isin([location_id])) & (quarter_hourly_data_df['phase'].isin([phase])) & (quarter_hourly_data_df['day_no'].isin([cur_day])) & (quarter_hourly_data_df['quarter_hour'].isin([quarter_hour]))]['timestamp']
                            # if data doesn't exist add row to missing data
                            if day_quarter_hour_data_check.empty:
                                location_phase_quarter_hour_missing_data.append({'location_id':location_id, 'phase':phase, 'day_no':cur_day, 'hour':pd.to_datetime(quarter_hour, format='%H:%M:%S').hour, 'quarter_hour':quarter_hour})

            else: #if phase doesn't exist add all rows to missing data

                for day_no in range(5):
                    cur_day = day_no+1

                    for quarter_hour in quarter_hours:
                        location_phase_quarter_hour_missing_data.append({'location_id':location_id, 'phase':phase, 'day_no':cur_day, 'hour':pd.to_datetime(quarter_hour, format='%H:%M:%S').hour, 'quarter_hour':quarter_hour})

location_phase_missing_data_df = pd.DataFrame(location_phase_quarter_hour_missing_data)
location_phase_missing_data_df.to_csv('location_phase_missing_rows.csv', index=False)
```

Are there other ways that are much faster to identify the missing rows or any way to optimize the code?

Comment: yes... but im not entirely clear on your requirement, how do you differentiate a device that was switched off vs missing rows? is it possible to provide a data subset that is complete with expected output for that data?

Comment: If the device wasn't switched on when the phase started then the initial rows that start at midnight are missing and the assumption is that the first row of data with the earliest timestamp for that phase was when the device got switched on. In the same rows I shared for the device 1005  the first available row is at 02:15:00 so the rows for timestamps before 02:15:00 are not considered as missing rows. In my code I find the start times for each phase with min of timestamp as look for missing rows after that time.

Comment: so any rows between midnight - whenever first that day are considered "switched off"?

Comment: yes, any rows from midnight of first day till the earliest available timestamp for that phase is considered as switched off and in very rare cases it can be on the 2nd or 3rd day of a phase when we see the earliest timestamp instead of the 1st day.

Answer (score 0):

Im not going to actually give you copy/paste code but rather the strategy I would employ for this, there are almost certainly a few errors in the below code

```
df = pandas.read_csv("input.csv")
# assume it looks something like the df listed above

def check_a_single_device_entries(entries):
    # sort by timestamp
    entries = entries.sort_values("timestamp")
    # get the diffs between timestamps
    diffs =  entries['timestamp'].shift(-1) - entries['timestamp']
    # return the error rows
    return entries[diffs != 15MINUTES]


# group by device/location
device_groups = df.groupby(["location_id","device_id"])
problems_per_device = device_groups.agg(check_a_single_device_entries)
print(problems_per_device) # from here you can probably get to your desired state
```

this mostly leverages the vectorized nature of pandas, causing you to effectively just manually iterate through each location/device combo which should in most cases be much faster than iterating through all the rows